# How do I make a Discord Bot to fetch all my private DMs with a user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord bot that writes the messages (either just my messages, just their messages, or preferably both) i have had with a user to the console.
I tried the following:

```
import requests
import json

DISCORD_TOKEN = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

CHANNEL_ID = '12345678901234567890'
MESSAGE_URL = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/messages/'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bot {DISCORD_TOKEN}'
}

def fetch_messages(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f'Failed to fetch messages. Status code: {response.status_code}')
        return None

# Fetch and print messages
messages = fetch_messages(MESSAGE_URL)
if messages:
    for message in messages:
        print(f'{message["author"]["username"]} ({message["author"]["id"]}): {message["content"]}')
else:
    print('No messages fetched.')
```

but get A 404 error. I have also tried this approach:

```
import discord
from discord import Intents
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'qdyglygyagfgdhiesdoafjarjhfasejksgldfhf'

intents = Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

    recipient_id = '57574664743777'
    recipient = client.get_user(recipient_id)

    if recipient:
        dm_channel = recipient.dm_channel
        if dm_channel:
            await fetch_messages(dm_channel)
        else:
            dm_channel = await recipient.create_dm()
            await fetch_messages(dm_channel)
    else:
        print('Recipient not found')


async def fetch_messages(channel):
    messages = []
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None):  # Fetch all messages
        messages.append(message.content)

    print(f'Fetched {len(messages)} messages:')
    for msg in messages:
        print(msg)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

but get told the recipient doesnt exist.

I have tried to grasp how all of this stuff works but can't seem to figure it out. Please help me

Comment: For your first attempt, it had absolutely nothing to do with `discord.py`. Your second attempt uses `get_user` which doesn't guarantee the user is in the cache which might also be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your second approach you should use `client.fetch_user` instead of `client.get_user` as `get_user` method trys to get user from its cache while `fetch_user`  gets it from discord.

The updated code will be:

```py
import discord
from discord import Intents
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'qdyglygyagfgdhiesdoafjarjhfasejksgldfhf'

intents = Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

    recipient_id = '57574664743777'
    recipient = await client.fetch_user(recipient_id) # here instead of get_user we are using fetch_user

    if recipient:
        dm_channel = recipient.dm_channel
        if dm_channel:
            await fetch_messages(dm_channel)
        else:
            dm_channel = await recipient.create_dm()
            await fetch_messages(dm_channel)
    else:
        print('Recipient not found')


async def fetch_messages(channel):
    messages = []
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None):  # Fetch all messages
        messages.append(message.content)

    print(f'Fetched {len(messages)} messages:')
    for msg in messages:
        print(msg)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Docs reference:

- [`await client.fetch_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_user#discord.Client.fetch_user)